# Linq IEnumerable to entity cast error

Tags: vb.net, linq

Please refer to my following code. An exception error occurs at the return value.
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[VB$AnonymousType_2`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyEntities.stk_cust]'.

```
Public Function GetCustomerProdListToGrid() As List(Of stk_cust)
        Dim result = From s In Db.stk_cust
             Group Join d In Db.s_armaster On d.dbcode Equals s.dbcode Into stk_ar = Group
             From d In stk_ar.DefaultIfEmpty()
             Order By s.stk_code, s.dbcode Ascending
             Select s.stk_code, s.dbcode, d.name
   Return result 
 End Function
```

I've tried the following method at select section but error turns out the same

```
Select New With {.stk_code = s.stk_code,
        .dbcode = s.dbcode,
        .name = d.name
  }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a `List(Of stk_cust)` you need to create instances of `stk_cust` instead of using an anonymous type. Presuming that those are the properties:

```
....
Select New stk_cust() With {
      .stk_code = s.stk_code,
      .dbcode = s.dbcode,
      .name = d.name
}

Return result.ToList()
```

---

Maybe you could also select the object  directly without needing to create a new one:

```
Dim result = From s In Db.stk_cust
             Group Join d In Db.s_armaster On d.dbcode Equals s.dbcode Into stk_ar = Group
             From d In stk_ar.DefaultIfEmpty()
             Order By s.stk_code, s.dbcode Ascending
             Select s
Return result.ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I will try your advice and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Tim, after tested with your first suggestion, I get an error, "The entity or complex type 'TotalModel.stk_cust' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query". For you second option, the query returns correct but I am unable to get the 'name' which is related to s_armaster.